# CSS - calculate percent minus dynamic image height

Tags: html, css

I have image with `width: 100%` so it's height is dynamic.
I want to place a div below it that will take all the height left to the bottom of the page. it is impossible to use `height: calc(100% - ... )` because the image height is unknown.

What is the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your markup please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution to do this is by using JavaScript.

You have to get image's height and than set div's height according to image's height.

First you have to get image's height using this:

```
var imgH = document.querySelector('my_img_selector').height;  //pure JS
var imgH = $('my_img_selector').outerHeight();                //jQuery
```

Than you have to get page height:

```
var pageH = window.innerHeight;  //pure JS - note that this may not work in all browsers
var pageH = $(window).height();  //jQuery
```

And than you have to set your div's height to fill rest of page

```
document.querySelector('my_div_selector').style.height = (pageH - imgH) + 'px';  //pure JS
$('my_div_selector').css('height', (pageH - imgH) + 'px');                         //jQuery
```

Tada! 
Hope I helped :D

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to use $('my_div_selector').css('height','calc(100%-'+imgHeight+')' ?

Comment: No, I don't think it should work. Anything you need to calculate is hard to perform in pure CSS. calc() function should be used to calculate different units with each other eg. % an px.

Comment: In addition to this setting DIV's height to any% won't work, because BODY height is calculated depending on content. You have to use pixels to do this.